# How can I run a CGI script properly in a ec2 instance running an Apache server

Tags: html, apache, perl, amazon-ec2, cgi

I am trying to follow this [tutorial on running a CGI script](http://www.lies.com/begperl/hello_cgi.html), but I am encountering some problems with how it is displayed.

I have the following CGI script located in a folder `scripts` in my html folder that Apache serves to me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# hello.pl -- my first perl script!

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

print <<"EOF";
<HTML>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>Hello, world!</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<H1>Hello, world!</H1>
</BODY>

</HTML>
EOF
```

When I run this script in the console (with `./hello.cgi`), I get the following correct output:

```
Content-type: text/html

<HTML>

<HEAD>
<TITLE>Hello, world!</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<H1>Hello, world!</H1>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

I am trying to access this on my ec2 instance with a URL like this: `http://<ec2-address>.compute-1.amazonaws.com/scripts/hello.cgi`. However, this is what I see:

[image: Screenshot of output on the server]

It is printing out the HTML correctly, but it is also printing everything else out as well.

What am I doing wrong here? Why am I getting a different output when I run the script on the server versus when I run it on the console *in* the server?

Comment: Running CGI in EC2 is the same as on any other Linux distro. Most likely your apache config is not set to execute the script.

Comment: You do not have a programming question. You have a question about [how to configure Apache to run CGI scripts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html#configuring).